# Restricting floating points (not string-wise)

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, precision

I'm making a NN (a small one that helps me learn) and I want to add self correcting increment to it. I know floating points aren't precise, but is there a way to make them so.

Here's my best go at it:

```
while (T - W) != 0.0:
    W = op
    T = self.learn(list_in, list_out, W, inc)

    if (T-W) < 0:
        if alternate == 0:
            alternate = -1
        elif alternate == 1:
            inc = inc/10
            alternate = -1
    elif (T-W) > 0:
        if alternate == 0:
            alternate = 1
        elif alternate == -1:
            inc = inc/10
            alternate = 1

    op = T
```

op - used to make my life easier, I know it looks bad

T - calculated weight

W - current weight

list_in/out - the file that simulates desired weights (will post if you need it)

inc - originally 0.1

alternate - it's supposed to be used to decrease increment by it's tenth

the function is supposed to be W*x, x being any integer, and W (weight) being 2

Now, if my weight is initially 30.0, in the next iteration it will be 29.9, and in the next iteration, it becomes 29.89999999999987... This results in my NN calculating the desired weight to be 1.9999999999999885, which is not the case, and the function returns false results at the 4th iteration. (input 3 is supposed to return 6, but it returns 5)

I know the 0.1 floating point is actually saved as 0.100000000000000000000123 or something in memory, but is there a way I can "strip" it, memory wise of the "123" part? I've tried rounding the 29.899... and it works, but if my weight isn't supposed to be a whole number, it would never pass, because it can only calculate the whole numbers. (I've made another test file with random number W*x, where W is 2.01891564)

To clarify: I don't want to print it out and see "0.1" I would like to somehow make sure that I've got only the 0.1, with no "extra" memory bits. Can it be done, and if not, what other approach can I try?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `Decimal` package?  Will that solve your problem?

Comment: From a floating point stand point, 0.1 and 0.100000000123 is not different at all. It's only different to your eye. Are you sure this is what caused your execution to fail?

Comment: @RockyLi yes, I'm positive, the increment doesn't change, I've checked.

Comment: @Prune I will make myself familiar, and I will get back at you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Prune suggested, I needed the `Decimal` package. Carefully changing floats in my code with Decimals solved my problem. If you want to make a Decimal, be sure to initialize it with string (i.e. 
`Decimal('0.1')`
and not with another float, because the result will be given float's actual representation in memory:

```
k = 0.1
p = Decimal(k)
t = Decimal('0.1')
print(p)
print(t)
```

> 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 | result of print p
>
> 0.1 | result of print t